# What is wrong with my Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, intellisense, error-list

So there is something wrong with my VS 2013.  Everything is up-to-date, IDE and OS (WIN 7). From my research several people say to delete the *.sdf file from my solution, I do not have such a file. Also suggested "Go to: Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache", that option is not there for me.

I can compile and run and everything is just fine and works as expected. If I make a single change the next time it compiles -- and EVERY time -- it comes up with false errors and sometimes hundreds of them.

All I have to do is clean and rebuild the project or whole solution usually.  But sometimes that doesn't even do the trick and I have to close VS and restart it and then the errors are all gone when I compile it again.

So it's not like it's preventing me from doing my job, however it is VERY annoying. **So the question is does anyone have any ideas of what I need to do or what settings need tweaked to fix this?** I had some issues a while back after a windows updated and ended up uninstalling and reinstalling VS 2013.  That was just a few months back too.  This current problem with the errors did not start after the reinstall, it just started happening in the last few weeks and continually is becoming more common.  Nothing I can think of has changed with my OS, VS or any other settings that would have caused this.

[image: Here is a small snip of my errors (there are over a hundred just like this)]

There are over a hundred errors similar to this and they're all false errors!
[image: Another screen shot to help show the issue(s)]

**EDIT: Added another screen shot that might help show my issue(s).**

**EDIT 2: I'd also like to mention that it's not just the intellisense messing up.  The code will not build nor can I run the project until a clean/rebuild or restart VS.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there has to be some better way to fix this problem or an explanation of how to prevent this from happening in the first place but here is how I managed to fix this issue.

I removed the contents of all the directories listed below. I just manually removed them but this could probably be setup as a batch to make the process effortless. But I'm not going to bother with that for now.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Users\<your-user-name>\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Backup Files
C:\Users\<your-user-name>\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Backup Files
C:\Users\<your-user-name>\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Backup Files
C:\Users\<your-user-name>\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3
C:\Users\<your-user-name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ProjectAssemblies
C:\Users\<your-user-name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ProjectAssemblies
C:\Users\<your-user-name>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ProjectAssemblies
```

To take a guess I think Visual Studio should be removing some if not all of these files.  Maybe in some cases the debugger crashes, or VS itself and some files are left behind and that might be what causes the intellisense / compiler errors.  Just a guess I wish I knew exactly why this happens.

**If someone knows of a better fix, or better yet a way to prevent the problem in the first place please enlighten me!**

> **EDIT:** This is just a temp fix, and probably not a very good one at that. It works for a while but eventually it starts happening again. I'll be making a batch file to clear the aforementioned directories so at least I can just have a one click fix. I just really wish I knew what the root cause of this was and how to prevent it in the first place.  --*03/17/2015*